# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python, python-2.7

¿Cómo arreglo este error?

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "main.py", line 7, in
>
> AreaL = (PI *(Generatriz * Radio))
>
> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Mi código es este:

```py
import math
PI =  3,1415
Diametro = int (raw_input("Ingrese el diametro del cono: \n"))
Profundidad = int (raw_input("Ingrese la profundidad del cono: \n"))
Radio = Diametro/2
Generatriz = math.sqrt(pow(Profundidad,2)+pow(Radio,2))
AreaL = (PI *(Generatriz * Radio))
AreaTotal = AreaL + (PI * (pow(Radio,2)))
Volumen = (PI * pow(Radio,3) * Profundidad)/3
if Volumen < 200.000:
   print "El deposito no es viable pues su volumen es %d metros cuadrados"%Volumen
if Profundidad < 20 or Profundidad > 250:
   print "El deposito no es viable pues tiene profundidad inadecuada"
if AreaTotal < 10.000:
   print "El deposito no es viable pues la base tiene area insuficiente: %f metros cuadrados"% AreaTotal    
else:
   print "El deposito es viable con volumen metros cubicos"% Volumen
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay 2 errores, el primero
`PI = 3,1415` (Reemplaza la coma por punto `3.1415`)

Y el segundo, en el `else`

```
print "El deposito es viable con volumen metros cubicos"% Volumen
```

falta el %d (o %f) dentro de la cadena.

```
print "El deposito es viable con volumen %f metros cubicos"% Volumen
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Recien estoy aprendiendo este lenguaje